# How do I run Release configuration on my device through Xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I can test a release configuration just fine in the simulator, but it doesn't work on my device. I can install the app package onto the device just fine, but it won't run directly from xcode. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go into the build settings for that target and change the Code Signing Identity for Release: Any iOS SDK to a developer profile instead of distribution. This will let you run a release configuration in the debugger. Just remember to revert it back to distribution when you submit!